# List all reachable nodes

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate that is bi-directional and tells, whether one node is connected to another.
E.g.

```
has(a, b).
has(b, c).
has(d, b).
```

Now I would like to list all nodes which can be reached (from a specific node) with a given number of steps.

```
connected_nodes(a, T, 2).
```

should therefore output

```
T = c 
T = d
```

My current code looks like this:

```
connected_nodes(A, B, 0) :- write(A).
connected_nodes(A, B, N) :- 
    N > 0, M is N - 1,
    has(A, X),
    connected_nodes(X, B, M).
```

This works for T = c but not for T = d, as this is a bi-directional relation.

Am I thinking correctly in terms of recursion or how in which other way does this problem have to be solved?

Comment: Do you want to include cycles or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `connected` predicate seems fine. It might have made more sense to make the base case rely on `has`, but it's up to you.

However, you *say* your `has` predicate is "bi-directional" but you haven't explicitly created a rule that indicates this.

The following code is a "bi-directional" version of your code:

```
has(a, b).
has(b, c).
has(d, b).

bi_has(X,Y) :- has(X,Y).
bi_has(X,Y) :- has(Y,X).

connected_nodes(A, B, 0) :- write(A).
connected_nodes(A, B, N) :- 
    N > 0, M is N - 1,
    bi_has(A, X),
    connected_nodes(X, B, M).
```

Note however that your query now returns `a` as a possible answer too. This makes since, because you never explicitly stated you don't want to return back to the same element after 2 steps.

If you don't want this behaviour, then you need to also keep a list of elements visited so far (i.e. an accumulator), and confirm that you're not revisiting elements.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the "backstepping" without accumulators by passing an additional variable which saves the previous visited node and returns false, when it equals the found node.

Comment: Well, that sounds like it will only work for a step number of 2 though. But if you don't care about the general case, then that's fine. :)

Comment: I guess it works as long as there are no circular references, which is fine for me :)